# How can I get emacs to open a new buffer quickly?

Tags: emacs, buffer

I used to be able to open a new buffer in Emacs quickly using the command `C-x b <non existent buffer name>`

Somehow I've broken this in my version of Emacs (23.1).  When ever I try to do this now I get the message `[No match]` in the command buffer.

Does anyone know what I might have done to break this functionality, or is it possible that I imagined being able to do this?

Comment: I'd suggest mentioning the result of C-h k C-x b (i.e. what is bound to the C-x b shortcut).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set `confirm-nonexistent-file-or-buffer` to `nil`:

```
confirm-nonexistent-file-or-buffer is a variable defined in `files.el'.
Its value is after-completion

Documentation:
Whether confirmation is requested before visiting a new file or buffer.
If nil, confirmation is not requested.
If the value is `after-completion', confirmation is only
 requested if the user called `minibuffer-complete' right before
 `minibuffer-complete-and-exit'.
Any other non-nil value means to request confirmation.

This affects commands like `switch-to-buffer' and `find-file'.

You can customize this variable.

This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
version 23.1 of Emacs.
```

Comment: I've added this to my .emacs but no dice. 
`;; Don't prompt for non existent name when creating temp buffers
(setq confirm-nonexistent-file-or-buffer nil)`

Can you spot anything that I've done that isn't correct?

Comment: It works as advertised here.  Do you have ido enabled as others have suggested?

Answer (score 7):

If you have enabled `ido-mode`, you can still switch to the behavior you're familiar with. I do this frequently when I know I'll be creating a new named buffer.

<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>C-b</kbd>

Comment: Also setting (setq ido-create-new-buffer 'always) might help.

Answer (score 3):

You press <kbd>C-j</kbd> instead of hitting enter twice, which will bypass the confirmation and immediately open the new buffer.  This works with or without `ido-mode`.  This will have the same effect has pressing enter with `confirm-nonexistent-file-or-buffer` set to `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably enabled `ido-mode`.  You need to press `ENTER` to confirm the creation of the buffer.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the cause.